# Moving Microsoft Dynamic CRM 2013 Servers

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I need to move dynamic CRM servers along with SQL Servers to one data center to another. I have new servers in the second DC and both DC's are accessible in different Subnet. What are my option to move this without much downtime?

We are using Microsoft Dynamic CRM 2013 and SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 1):

If you are keeping the same hostnames and just changing the IPs - then it should be just a matter of copying the VMs and then changing the IPs. A reboot, and you should be good. 
Just check the registry to make sure you are using hostnames and not IP addresses. Check this location: `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\MSCRM`

Comment: Thanks Donal. I need to change the hostname :( as servername we keep the datacenter name as prefix.